# How to custom all headers in v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-data-table

I'm trying to customize all headers in my `v-data-table` like this

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          :disable-sort="true"
          :hide-default-footer="true"
        >
          <template v-slot:header="{ header }">
            {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
          </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I saw in the documentation how to do this for only ONE header like this :

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          :disable-sort="true"
          :hide-default-footer="true"
        >
          <template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
            {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
          </template>
</v-data-table>
```

but I want to custom ALL headers and I'm not figuring out how to do this. Also my headers are dynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `header` (not `header.<name>`) slot. Note that this slot is used for **generating all header columns at once**. It means that you'll need to dynamically create the `<th>` tags using a `v-for` directive.

Also, it is located under the default headers, so you'll need to add the `hide-default-header` prop.

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" hide-default-header>
    <template v-slot:header="{ props }">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">
                    {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

See this [working example](https://codepen.io/chamboug/pen/PozarZj?editors=1011).